# Does neo4j community/enterprise/desktop works without internet

Tags: neo4j

I am working on a project and I want neo4j to perform all the functions without getting connected to the internet.Is it possible in community/desktop/enterprise edition ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a yes for all !

For neo4j CE and EE, you must have a Java installed before.

For the desktop, it comes with everything (a java runtime + the binary of the database). The only thing you will not be able to do without internet connection is to install some graph applications and also to choose a specific version of the database.